# Custom UITableViewCell does not show the labels in storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

[image: Custom UITableViewCell in UITableView]

[image]

In this screen shot you can see that I have added UITableView in UIViewController then customized the UITableViewCell by adding some labels in it. But the issue is when I run the application. All of the cells are empty. There are no labels at all.

[image: Empty Cells]

I am not getting what can be the issue. I have searched the web and read tutorials but couldn't resolve it.

Comment: How are you adding the cells to the table view? Can you paste your table view delegate methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue by myself, just after little effort.
Actually when you create a custom cell you have to do these things:

1. Setup the labels, images etc on storyboard cell.
2. Create a custom cell class (inheriting from UITableViewCell)(CustomCell.h & .m), CustomCell.h having all of the properties as iboutlet for labels, images etc. and synthesize them all in implementation.
3. After creating this custom class go back to storyboard, select the custom cell, change its class to the CustomCell and give it some identifier like "MyCustomCell", then right click on the custom cell and connect the IBOutlets with labels etc.
4. Now import CustomCell class in the class where you are implementing the UITableView and use the properties you defined in CustomCell class.

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

       CustomCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

       if (cell == nil)
       {
           cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
       }

       // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
       // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
       [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
           cell.myCustomLabel.text = @"My Text";
       return cell;
   }
   ```

I did this all and my issue was resolved and please don't forget to connect the delegates & datasource and table.

Hope this will help others.

Comment: Shouldn't [UITableViewCell alloc] actually be [CustomCell alloc]

Comment: The important part is the cell identifier. Make sure it is the same in both the Storyboard and the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

It is little bit late but you can solve your problem by setting the background color of your view as Clear Color from your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

in the tableview's delegate method , cellforrowatindexpath has a uitableviewcell inside it , there should be an identifier in the initialization of this cell. possibly it is "cell" or "cellIdentifier" .

you just need to select your cell from storyboard and enter this identifier string to the storyboard , where uitableviewcell's attribute inspector stays.

hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First Set cell identifier in storyboard @"Cell"

then set tag of label

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Create
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}



UILabel *lblDate = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
UILabel *lblDistance = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel *lbltype = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:103];

lblDate.text = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"/"]];
lblDistance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ KM",[[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"distance"]];

NSString *type = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"distance"]];
if([type isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    lbltype.text = @"Personal";
}
else
{
    lbltype.text = @"Bussiness";
}
// Configure
return cell;
}
```